# How to sum all elements in a tuple

Tags: swift, tuples

In Swift, i.e. a tuple `let tp = (2,5,8)`.

What's the simplest and smartest way to sum it up, other than traditionaly as below?

`let sum = tp.0 + tp.1 + tp.2`

Comment: Do you have a particular  reason not to use an array? Tuples can contain different kinds of values.

Comment: I'm not saying that it is not possible, but – unless you restrict it to a certain tuple type such as integer triples – it requires introspection at runtime, and the compiler can not check the correctness.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is the most straightforward. An alternative is harder to read, but it works, too:

```
let s = Mirror(reflecting: x).children.map {$1 as! Int}.reduce(0,+)
```

`Mirror(reflecting: x).children` obtains a sequence of name-value pairs representing the original tuple. Each element of the sequence is a `(String,Any)` tuple. `map {$1 as! Int}` converts this sequence to a sequence of `Int`s representing tuple element values; `reduce(0,+)` produces the sum of these values.

You can combine `map` and `reduce` in a single expression for something even less readable:

```
let s = Mirror(reflecting: x).children.reduce(0,{$0.1.value as! Int + $0.0})
```

**Note:** It goes without saying that this crashes at runtime for tuples containing values of type other than `Int`.

Comment: One should at least mention that this crashes if the tuple contains something else than only `Int`s

Comment: @MartinR I think this is self-evident from the `$1 as! Int` part, but I guess a little note wouldn't hurt. Thanks!

Comment: If you used `as? Int` and `flatMap`, you could safely add up all of the `Int`s and ignore the others.

Comment: @vacawama This would no longer be equivalent to OP's example, though, where he adds up all elements of his tuple.

Comment: @vacawama: A runtime crash (which shows immediately that you have a programming error) might be preferable to  a (silent) wrong result.

Comment: What about a sum for a tuple containing `Int` and `Double`? `let x = (1, 2.3);
let s = Double(Mirror(reflecting: x).children.flatMap {$1 as? Int}.reduce(0,+)) + Mirror(reflecting: x).children.flatMap {$1 as? Double}.reduce(0,+)`

Comment: @vacawama I think this expands the scope of what has started as `tp.0 + tp.1 + tp.2` way too much to be usable.